# Scan directory for file names in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, upload, directory, filenames

I'm developing a MVC5 web app, hosted through azure, that lets you manage your movies (it's just for myself at the moment). I'm trying to find a way to scan a local folder on the users pc for a list of file names. I do realise the security/permissions issues I might run into. I do not need the file uploaded, only the full file name.

It would work by the user being able to select a folder where they store their movies and it will take in all the file names, including the ones in any sub directories.

I tried a multiple file upload form but quickly ran into issues with the max request limit which I tried messing around with but it proved redundant in the end. I can settle for the user selecting multiple files but would rather it done the directory way.

I know this might prove impossible in the end but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not completely clear about your problem. Do you have the issue with uploading many files at the same time or scanning them on the server?

Comment: I simply want the app to take in the all the names of the files in a folder the user selects

Comment: Is that folder on a server or on user's PC?